# Switching between multiple accounts in the Discord desktop application?

Tags: windows, discord

I'd like to set up some way to easily switch between Discord accounts using the Discord desktop application in Windows. Unfortunately the desktop app does not have this feature built in.

I'm aware of ways of switching between accounts in the Discord web app, such as by using containers in Firefox, or an app like Franz, Rambox, or Shift. However the desktop app has certain features that aren't available in the web app, like advanced noise suppression, so I'd like to do this in the desktop app if possible.

After looking into this for basically a minute, it looks like Discord stores all of its data in `%APPDATA%` and `%LOCALAPPDATA%`, so I'm thinking I could write a script that quits Discord if it's running, swaps out some folders in those depending on which account I want to use, and then relaunches Discord. I haven't actually tested this, though.

Is there a better way, or perhaps an existing solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to hack up a solution for this, Discord now features an [account switcher](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/4412732047127-Discord-Account-Switcher-FAQ) that allows for the ability to quickly switch between alternate accounts.

To set this up, left click your avatar in the lower-left of the Discord app and hover over "Switch accounts," then click "Manage accounts" to add additional accounts. To switch, simply open up the "Switch accounts" menu again and select the account you want to switch to.

The account switcher currently supports quickly switching between up to 5 accounts. Switching between more would require a more nuanced solution.